# Why does this observable become a computed / dependent when passed into component?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-3.2

I have a simple model, and on there is an observable ("model.thing"). I then set an additional observable on this ("someProp") and pass it into the params of a component.

```
model.thing = ko.observable({});
model.thing.someProp = ko.observable("Yolo");
```

At this point the observable has become a computed and i'm not sure why.

If i change the model so that instead of having `model.thing` as an observable i have it as a simple object and then pass that in, it is coming through without changing into a computed...

Does anyone have an explanation for this behaviour?

Here's a working example (it alerts the param which shows that it has become a computed).

http://liveweave.com/MozLiW

```js
var viewModel = function() {
    var model = {};
 model.thing = ko.observable({}); //when thing is observable
   //model.thing = {};
 model.thing.someProp = ko.observable("Yolo");
 
    
  return model;
};

ko.components.register('custom-element', {
    viewModel: function(params) {
        this.value = params.value;
       alert(this.value); //then this is dependent, why?!
    }, 
    template:
    '<div data-bind="text: value"></div>'
});

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.js"></script>

<title>Knockout component</title>
</head>
<body>
  <custom-element params="value: thing().someProp"></custom-element>
<!--   
<custom-element params="value: thing.someProp"></custom-element> -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: See: http://www.knockmeout.net/2014/06/knockout-3-2-preview-components.html **How params are passed to the component** for the explanation of this behavior.

Comment: I see thanks, so in order to solve the problem this was providing me (setting the value), i will need to use params.$raw.value(); Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to nemesv, he pointed me to [this](http://www.knockmeout.net/2014/06/knockout-3-2-preview-components.html) which explains it.

> The params object supplied when using the custom element syntax will
>   also include a $raw property (unless the params happens to supply a
>   property with that same name) which gives access to computeds that
>   return the original value (rather than the unwrapped value).

### For example:

```
<my-component params="value: selectedItem().value"></my-component>
```

> In this case, since selectedItem is accessed, the param is supplied as
>   a computed. When the computed is accessed, the unwrapped value is
>   returned to avoid having to double-unwrap a param to get its value.
>   However, you may want access to the value observable in this case,
>   rather than its unwrapped value. In the component, this could be
>   achieved by accessing `params.$raw.value()`. The default functionality
>   is slanted towards ease of use (not having to unwrap a param twice)
>   while providing `$raw` for advanced cases.